# 'NavController)' has its 'NIB Name' property set to 'VerwaltungsTableView.nib',... manner

Tags: objective-c, nib

I want to build an Application with UITables and a DetailView.
But I got now a warning called:

> 'Selected Verwaltung Nav Controller (Verwaltung)' has its 'NIB Name' property set to 'VerwaltungsTableView.nib', but this view controller is not intended to have its view set in this manner.

But I think I have the Objects in the right manner. [Here](http://www.joelschmid.ch/error2.jpg) and [here](http://www.joelschmid.ch/error3.jpg) you can see the errors and the InterfaceBuilder.

What causes this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Navigation controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1) are meant to organise other view controllers.  You aren't supposed to lay them out yourself.  You're supposed to create other view controllers, assign one of them as the navigation controller's root view controller, then write code to let the user navigate to the other view controllers from there.

If you're trying to get the table view controller nib to show up, then you should probably be assigning the table view controller to the navigation controller's `rootViewController` property.